# Can't list all objects in bucket with boto3 but can with AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I'm having an issue with boto3 where I can't list all objects in a bucket by just providing the bucket name. When I just provide bucket name, I get an access denied issue. I can however, use `aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name` and I can view all objects.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(file.key)
```

The above gode gives access denied.

[image]

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name --recursive
```

This code works, it lists everything from the top level prefix.

In boto3, if I specify a specific prefix, 2 levels down I can list all objects. Like this

```
for file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="dir_name/sub_dir"):
    print(file.key)
```

From what I can understand, I am using IAM role credentials, as no credential file or env. variables are set on my machine. The bucket I'm trying to list is outside of my AWS account.

What's confusing me is why I'm seeing slightly different behavior with AWS CLI vs boto3. I believe I have correct list bucket policy because I can list with AWS CLI. Is that a flawed assumption?

Comment: It seems to be a permission issue - as I do not see any difference in output with boto3 and cli - from my end.

is AWS cli command and python program executed from different environment ?

Comment: @GowthamChand yep, ran from the same exact command prompt.

Comment: Can you list out the IAM permission for this role ?

Comment: @GowthamChand when I try aws iam list-roles I get SSL: Certificate_Verify_Failed